# Is Pascal used anywhere anymore?

Tags: pascal

I'm in High School learning Pascal and it's the most frustrating language i've ever coded in, I'm trying to learn other languages like JavaScript and its libraries and frameworks. I just want to know if it's worth learning Pascal or if I should focus more on JavaScript.

Comment: How many languages have you been coding in? You should consider that modern versions of Pascal, like Delphi, offer a lot of things not present in old-school Pascal (like classes and objects, generics, anonymous methods, and operator overloading).

Comment: on job market pascal(clasic-turbo) is inexistent and if any then this might be a miracle. Related to coding and learning the basics pascal is still a very good  tool. Mainly learning any programming language is good way to boost the knowledge.

Comment: Pascal is the best language to start learning programming. Don't mind that it's not widely used. It is low level and strict. You will learn, how to deal with pointers and create complex data structures. Much better for a novice then Javascript or any scripting language. When you learn Pascal well enough, Javascript will be easy.

Comment: https://github.com/peazip/PeaZip  use pascal

Answer (score 2):

I work in a company whose softwares are all made using Delphi (a more modern, object-oriented, proprietary version of Turbo Pascal from Embarcadero) and, honestly? It's a very nice language to code with...
Pure Pascal, however, is likely not worth focusing too much time and energy on.

It all depends on what you desire to code: either websites, mobile apps, databases, services, desktop apps...

Comment: I also do Delphi programming for a living. It's not unheard of (but uncommon compared to C, C++, Python, Java, C# etc.)